# Texture getting stretched on sides of the shape

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, objects, uv-image-editor

I followed the following steps to create the shape and apply the texture

1. Imported SVG
2. Converted to Mesh and cleaned shape
3. Extruded on the z-axis
4. Applied PBR from poly haven also tried to apply Texture from Adobe Substance 3d

To fix sides having stretched texture I tried

- UV unwrapping faces
- UV smart project
- Marked seams
- Correct face attributes were ticked while creating the shape
- Manual fixes via UV editor didn't fix texture issues on the Object

[image]

Comment: Here is the blender file
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1P4UEAwalDE15SAhMANaSTjFuKW71pOLx?usp=share_link

Comment: Did you apply the scale to your object in Object mode (Ctrl-A > Scale) before unwrapping it?

Comment: Yes, I did apply scale

Comment: Ok. Most of the 200 Meg size of that zip archive appears to be the zip file of rocks which are irrevelant to your problem so could have been left out. Also the texture file is in Substance format (.sbsar) which requires an external addon to be used in Blender that I don't have so I can't really help any further.